# Where can I download Visual C++ Express

Tags: visual-c++

Sorry for asking such dumb question. I just want to download Visual C++ 2010 Express edition.  I've selected the language on this page http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2010-Visual-CPP and it redirected me to http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/87W7256K-0T322Q4X-PD0OU915/disclaimer.aspx with neither a started download or a download link.

I'm unable to download it

Answer (score 0):

Which browser are you using?

The final screen you get to is the confirmed download screen.

You may have a download window in the background (IE or FF) or a Save button in your status bar (Chrome)

Also, if you are using IE it may have briefly presented you with a yellow security bar at the top to confirm the download before automatically redirecting to the confirmation page. (Not very useful!)

Comment: I have tried in FF,IE,Chrome.In none of these there is any download

Comment: Are you behind a corporate firewall or proxy?